what would make mountains move as waves on liquid
I like the idea of mountains that move like water waves, with a period of centuries.  Can you rationalize that sans magic?
I envision a thin rubbly crust on a viscous liquid mantle, but intuition suggests the waves would not last long.

This is pretty much what happens --- except the periodicity is more like tens of millions of years. I also think you're well on your way to answering your own question!

Let's start with a research project.

You might check out the mega landslides in Utah and how they moved over the land at 200 miles per hour.  https://geology.utah.gov/map-pub/survey-notes/utahs-ancient-mega-landslides/

Do you want your world to be still liveable?

Tidal Heating and Mountain Formation:
Mountains are caused mostly by tectonic activity, and what we are doing is basically creating a new mountain, a short distance away from the old one, repeating that ad infinitum.
Speeding up the formation of mountains would require increasing tectonic activity significantly, likely by orders of magnitude. One way to achieve this is by using tidal heating, which can heat up a planets core and increase tectonic processes.
Take IO as example:

As Io orbits Jupiter in an elliptical fashion, the strength of
Jupiter's gravity on Io varies depending on how close the moon is to
the gas giant. This gravitation fluctuation creates a perpetual push
and pull on the moon's interior in different directions, which causes
Io's surface to bulge by as much as 330 feet (100 meters), according
to NASA. This movement causes Io's rocks to grind past each other,
generating vast quantities of heat — 20 times more heat flow than
Earth.

For your scenario, tidal heating could play a crucial role in reshaping mountains. If you have a moon orbiting a large planet with multiple moons exerting tidal forces, these interactions could cause intense internal heating for a sustained period (as long as the orbit remains), promoting tectonic activity continuously. This would allow mountains to be formed and reshaped faster than here on Earth.
Your initial idea of a thin rubbly crust on a viscous liquid mantle would help make it easier to move the mountains, and the orbits should help the effect last for a long while. While not entirely the same thing, Europa's liquid water underneath icy sheets could be a kind of example what a more liquid mantle would do.

I am uncertain if I did that quote correctly. (do I need to add author information?)
